# Is there a quotient of $c_0$ without the approximation property?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

The famous example of Enflo of a Banach space without the approximation property is actually a subspace of $c_0$. Is there a quotient of $c_0$ without the approximation property?

This would follow if we knew that each subspace of $c_0$ is isomorphic to its quotient, however we know only the opposite case.

Comment: Yes.  Probably it is mentioned in A. Szankowski's most recent single author paper.